# gh-pages will not refresh after CircleCI build

Tags: python, git, python-sphinx, github-pages, circleci

I have a python package with documentation built by sphinx, and a gh-pages branch setup for github pages. I have a script that when run locally will  publish my changes without issue. At the end of a CircleCI test cycle the script runs without errors but the changes will not show in the actual page. The changes are however shown in index.html of the gh-pages branch.

Recap

1. Make changes locally.
2. ./deploy_docs.sh
3. Verify changes <- They appear
4. Make changes, push to github, have CircleCI run test
5. CircleCI runs ./deploy_docs.sh
6. index.html on gh-branch reflects changes. Website does not host new index.html

My deploy script:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

git checkout gh-pages
git pull --unshallow origin gh-pages

git reset --hard origin/$CIRCLE_BRANCH

sphinx-apidoc -o docs/source dslib
sphinx-build docs/source .

git add -A
git commit -m "Deploy to GitHub pages $CIRCLE_SHA1 [ci skip]"
git push -f origin gh-pages
```

Why are the gh-pages not being updated after being pushed to gh-pages from CircleCI?

Comment: CircleCI does a shallow clone during checkout instead of a regular one. Perhaps this is the cause of your issue?

Comment: I added a git `pull --unshallow origin gh-pages` which made no difference.

Comment: I had a similar behaviour where gh-pages branch was being updated but the website didn't show any changes. In my case, broswer was caching the page. Maybe clear your browser's cache?

Comment: Thank you but I checked and it's not a caching issue.

Comment: Worked with github and found they had blocked the machine user from CircleCi. That explanation seems off given that the CircleCi was still able to push to the gh-pages repo. Either way, problem solved.